# Replacing a String in a command script

Tags: cmd, command, copy-paste

I am new to CMD Commands, what I am looking for is the CMD should ask for the start and end number and then replace it between the parantheses. Also can the CMD also ask to select the source file, and also it should ask the folder to paste the files which is in code sample.

Thanks Again

```
@ECHO off 
SET /P start=Please enter Starting Number: 
SET /P end=Please enter Ending  Number:
for /L %f in  (echo %start%,1,echo %end%) do copy I:\EXP\new.txt I:\EXP\new-%f.txt
```

Comment: Check out [this site](http://ss64.com) it has a great list of all commands for most operating systems with examples and explanations. This is just a batch file and you cant directly do things like opening a file dialog. You would need to have the user type or copy/paste the answer themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `echo` here. You want to *use* the number not *print* it.

it's just:

```
 for /L %%f in (%start%,1,%end%) do ...
```

(also note the `%%f`. In batchfiles, you have to double the percent sign)

To ask for the source file and destination folder, just use two more `set /p` commands.

Comment: You are genius... @Stephan